# Many models to view with many partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that contains many partial views and I need to pass to each one the matching model.

I've found 2 ways to do this, but I don't know whats the real way it should be done.

1. I thought of creating big class that contain all the models as properties and than i can send the models to each partial view. the problem is that its hard typed, and if i need to pass a diffrent combination of models it wont fit.
2. The other way I though of is having a methods in each model that bring me the model for each partial view (GetMenuBar() and so on).

Whats the right way doing that?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by this: "`the problem is that its hard typed, and if i need to pass a diffrent combination of models it wont fit.`"?

Comment: This sounds like a great candidate for interface segregation - have the model object implement an interface for each partial it's powering.

Comment: @arootbeer I agree, that's exactly what I use in my current project. As well as abstract and/or inherited classes for the VMs

Comment: Yakimych - I thought its 'Hard codded' to create for every big view many models as properties since it makes every view dedicated with specific views for specific partial views, but now I understand it is completely normal.

arootbeer - Having interfaces that have "GetX"/"GetY" methods makes sense. I wonder if there is another use for that interfaces beside this kind of methods (GetArticles/GetUsers). 


I  don't know if it is legit to create logics inside a model class.


AlfalfaStrange - Did you insert methods inside the model class that actually have logics inside and not used as DAL only?

Comment: @Aviran no my models don't have any logic in them, I handle the data gathering at the controller level, that is to say my methods in my controller actions use my BLL and that uses my DAL. So in my controller I will have model.Entity = entityInstance.GetByID(id); to return an instance of that class. That instance calls into the DAL to get the data from the db

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My advice, go with Option 1. I use that with all of my Main View/Multiple Partial View scenarios. It's easy to maintain as each partial has it's own ViewModel. It keeps the whole thing nice and clean

I use the exact same setup like so:

```
public class MainViewModel {

    public Partial1ViewModel Partial1 [ get; set; }
    public Partial2ViewModel Partial2 [ get; set; }
    public Partial3ViewModel Partial3 { get; set; }
    public Partial4ViewModel Partial4 { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel() {}

    public MainViewModel() {
        Partial1 = new Partial1ViewModel();
        Partial2 = new Partial2ViewModel();
        Partial3 = new Partial3ViewModel();
        Partial4 = new Partial4ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Each `PartialViewXViewModel` is it's own ViewModel and if need be can be reused in another view.

Your Action that renders can look like so:

```
public ActionResult Index {
    var model = new MainViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your View

```
@model MainViewModel

<div>
    {@Html.RenderPartial("PartialOne", Model.Partial1)}
</div>


<div>
    {@Html.RenderPartial("PartialTwo", Model.Partial2)}
</div>


<div>
    {@Html.RenderPartial("PartialThree", Model.Partial3)}
</div>


<div>
    {@Html.RenderPartial("PartialFour", Model.Partial4)}
</div>
```

Define the UI for each `PartialX` like:

```
@model Partial1ViewModel

//view html here
```

Now, each Partial view html and each model that they use can be used anywhere.

The great part is now if you have a page that needs only 2 of these you just create a new `ViewModel` to represent that specific view like so:

```
public class OtherMainViewModel {

    public Partial2ViewModel Partial2 [ get; set; }
    public Partial4ViewModel Partial4 { get; set; }

    public OtherMainViewModel() {}

    public OtherMainViewModel() {
        Partial2 = new Partial2ViewModel();
        Partial4 = new Partial4ViewModel();
    }
}
```

And use it in another view like so:

```
public ActionResult SomeOtherAction {
    var model = new OtherMainViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

And that's perfectly acceptable and also the preferred design strategy in MVC, to have ViewModels that specifically represent what a view needs and only what it needs.

You may want to use a different method for populating your models tho. Most here would recommend using Automapper. Either way, the above just initializes the PartialViewXModels in the constructor of the MainViewModel. That won't necessarily be your case if you are populating those models with data from your DB. You would want your own strategy for that. This would work here:

```
public ActionResult Index {
    var model = new MainViewModel();
    model.Partial1 = GetPartial1Data(); // this method would return Partial1ViewModel instance
    model.Partial2 = GetPartial2Data(); // same as above for Partial2ViewModel
    ...
    return View(model);
}
```

This all would just get you started with the design, you can tweak it to your hearts content :-)

Comment: You create "MainViewModel" for each page?
for example - "MainPageViewModel", "ArticlesPageViewModel" and so on,
or you have in every control/page pass the same model and u use what you need? the second option I can understand u can use whatevery property you want, its not over header?

Comment: If you have more than one page that uses all of those partials then yes, you use the ViewModel that that page represents. If you have a page that does not need all of those partials then you create a different ViewModel as seen in my answer update at the end

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot about the MVC perspective of design  :)

Comment: I haven't tested this solution, however I can see problems arising when the same ViewModel is used twice, and you need prefixes to be prepended to each field.  For instance, you have 2 AddressViewModel classes rendered on the same page.  One is Mailing Address, one is Street Address.  You cannot have the same ID for the two ViewModels, so you'd have to come up with some way to prepend those prefixes to each field.  EditorFor will take care of this, but then you end up with "#MainViewModel_Partial1_ZipCode".  However, this is only a big concern when using JavaScript to do anything.