# Remove Prefix from ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, model-binding

I have a ViewModel class composed of several nested classes:

```
 public class UserAccountViewModel : UserProfileViewModel
    {
        public UserAccountEmailViewModel UserAccountEmail { get; set; }
        public UserAccountLocationViewModel UserAccountLocation { get; set; }
        public UserAccountPasswordViewModel UserAccountPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

The HTML rendered from this (pay attention to  **model.UserAccountEmail.Email**):

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAccountEmail.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAccountEmail.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAccountEmail.Email)
    </div>
```

Is this:

```
name="UserAccountEmail.Email"
```

I would prefer the name to simply be `Email`

Changing `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` didn't help. Overloading the `htmlFieldName` in `@Html.EditorFor` isn't going to work because I still want the label and validation message to match the rendered HTML element (no overload for htmlFieldName in these functions).

I'd prefer to not create partials for this.

**Edit:**

**Meh...using partials actually isn't too bad. It actually makes quite a lot of sense.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer here about this design, it might make sense for this particular strategy

[Many models to view with many partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769997/many-models-to-view-with-many-partial-views/10770097#10770097)

Comment: yeah i like the approach using partial views

Comment: @scoarescoare glad it helped, like you said, it just makes sense